# Deleting last characters from a cell in Microsoft Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I delete everything but the first 6 characters in a cell throughout a whole column?

The cells contain identification numbers and in some cases more identifications have been made in each row. I am ony interested in the first identification number of 6 characters, consisting of both letters and numbers.

Ex: `X47551;X85H52;X14J56`

So how do I remove everything but the 'X47551'?

Comment: This function is what you need: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/len-lenb-HP005209154.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP003056120.

Answer (score 3):

You could create another column that uses a formula to pull only the 6 left characters:

`=LEFT(A1,6)` where A1 = "X47551;X85H52;X14J56"

After using the formula you may want a column of the text that no longer depends on it.  This could replace your original column, if desired:

1. Select the column
2. Right click -> *Copy*
3. Select another blank column
4. Right click -> *Paste special...*
5. Select Paste **Values** -> *Ok*

Alternatively, you may want to split the existing column by the semicolon delimiter:

1. Select the column
2. Navigate to *Data* -> *Text to Columns*
3. Select **Delimited** -> *Next*
4. Select **Other** -> Enter ';' -> *Next*
5. Change format, if desired -> *Finish*

This will change a single column of "X47551;X85H52;X14J56" into three columns of "X47551", "X85H52", and "X14J56".